# Spring JSR303-like validation with HttpServletRequest awareness

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am willing to incorporate JSR303-like validation, which would be aware of related `HttpServletRequest`.

For example, Re-Captcha requires to send IP of user who is solving the CAPTCHa alongside with challenge and response and for that i need something like `HttpServltRequest.getRemoteAddr()`, so for validating form, containing ReCAPTCHa with annotations/corresponding validators transparently for the controller (like, annotating POJO with something like `@ReCaptcha`) i need such instance in validation layer.

Ideally, i want to inject my validation logic between

```
[Http Servlet Request] -> [Jackson or similar data bind of request parts to POJO]
```

and

```
@RequestMapping("somewhere")
@ResponseBody
public Object login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginData loginData) {
    ...
}
```

call.

Which Spring facilities exists for implementing such validation?

I've found `HandlerInterceptor` concept which acts a bit before i wanted it to, right after forming `HttpServletRequest`, before binding of request data to objects seems to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i've found something usable:

In controller' class, add

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpServletRequest request) {
    binder.addValidators(new ReCaptchaValidator(request));
}
```

This `@InitBinder`-annotated method would be called before each controller `@RequestMapping`-methods. You could refine this selection by providing as annotation value a list of model attributes name to trigger on.

And `ReCaptchaValidator` is a mere implementation of `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface.

Arguments, which could be used in this `@InitBinder`-method are, as documentation says, similar to `@RequestMapping` controller methods:

```
* <p>Such init-binder methods support all arguments that {@link RequestMapping}
* supports, except for command/form objects and corresponding validation result
* objects. Init-binder methods must not have a return value; they are usually
* declared as {@code void}.
*
* <p>Typical arguments are {@link org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder}
* in combination with {@link org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest}
* or {@link java.util.Locale}, allowing to register context-specific editors.
```